# Android Not Receiving Response from PHP Server

Tags: php, android, http, wamp, httpurlconnection

For debugging purposes, my PHP server is echoing a very simple string to my Android client:

```
<?php echo "I REALLY LIKE PIE" ?>
```

My Android client has the following code to receive such a string:

```
URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.107/index.php");
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.connect();

        int HTTPResult = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        if (HTTPResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            String output = "";
            while ((output = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                returnedString.append(output);
            }
            bufferedReader.close();

        }

        urlConnection.disconnect();
```

However, the variable "output" is null, and thus the returned string is also null. Why am I getting no response?

Comment: http://192.168.0.107/index.php is a local ip and probably its not accessible with your android device.

Comment: Is connection successful ? Whats the value of HTTPResult ?

Comment: 192.168.0.107 it's your network ip address or you system ip address where your project is setup ?

if it's your system ip address then it's don't going to work directly.
if it's network ip address and your project is setup on server then you can connect device to network (over wifi). and make project resources shared you can access it.

Comment: I see that There is no semi colon in your echo statement , is it a typo ?

Comment: Yeah that is a typo. I have a statement that sends data to the server, and the server executes it perfectly. However, my Android client can't receive. HTTPResult is 200, which is good. 1.107 is the local host of the WAMP Server.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add the logs given for debugging purposes or use the android debugger with breakpoints.
2. Make sure you have done required changes in the php config file for making it accessible via your phone.
   It should work. Let me know if the problem persists. (I have been using this code with some minor changes for parsing the JSON Objects afterwards but since its just a string in your case it should work.
3. For much better, easier and optimized, **Use OkHttp or Volley**

   ```
   URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.107/index.php");
   urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   BufferedReader reader = null;

   urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
   urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
   urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
   urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
   urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
   urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
   urlConnection.connect();

   // Read the input stream into a String
   InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
   StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
   if (inputStream == null) {

   // Nothing to do.

   }
   reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

   String line;
   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect        parsing)
    // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
    // buffer for debugging.
    buffer.append(line + "\n");
   }


   bufferedReader.close();

   }

   urlConnection.disconnect();
   ```

Comment: What changes in the Apache httpd.conf file should I make? I am not into other libraries, and I prefer to complete this task with libraries given by the 23rd API.

Comment: In the httpd.conf file, fine the term Deny from all change it to Allow from all. Did the code above work? Any logs u recieved in the console?